# Graphical Git clients

Tags: linux, git

I'm looking for a Git GUI that covers all my needs in one place. Currently I'm using 4 different tools in parallel and while that gets the job it would be nice to have it all in one place. The tools I'm currently using are gitk, gitg, Git GUI and meld. The features I'm looking for (and how they are supported by the these 4 tools) are:

1. View local changes (meld(side by side), Git GUI(diff only), gitg(diff only))
2. Commit  (meld (whole files only), gitg (whole files only), Git GUI (per hunk and and per line))
3. Revert local changes (meld, gitg (whole files only))
4. History browsing (gitk, gitg (not on bare repos))
5. Historical diff (gitk (diff only))
6. Clean simple interface (gitg, Git GUI, meld)

I don't tend to tag or branch much so I'm still doing those from the command line, but I can imagine needing them in a tool eventually, gitg can tag, gitk seems to be able to do a variety of stuff in that area.

Is there any Linux tool that covers all of these?

Comment: See [Best Git GUI on MacOS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83789/what-is-the-best-git-gui-on-osx) for one set of related answers.

Comment: @Jonathan: Except *Linux* tool is specifically asked for here.

Comment: @Jan: that's why it is a comment about related answers, not an answer.  Some of the tools also run on Linux, I believe.  It is also why there isn't a 'exact duplicate' close out there - this question isn't an exact duplicate of that one.

Comment: magit is not graphical but it does support all of those things, I think!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux not sure if there is anything out there that covers all bases perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [list of git guis on git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/i/n/t/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools.html) and it has a [feature matrix at the end of "Graphical Interfaces" section](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/i/n/t/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools.html#Summary_.28feature_matrix.29), so look for yourself. It seems "git-cola" is the most featureful, but I didn't try it, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

There is RabbitVCS - http://rabbitvcs.org/

I know it is a good enough SVN client, not sure about Git support

Answer (score 0):

There is [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). I think it's the best git client for Linux. It is free for non-commercial use.
[image]